# How to assign cloned functions to new this instance

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I have following code, written in ES6 plus some Stage 3 proposals:

```
class Parent {
  constructor(x){
    this.x = x;
    this.otherProperty = "preserve across copy";
  }

  printX=()=>{
    console.log(this.x);
  }

  squareX=()=>{
    this.x = this.x *this.x; 
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  constructor(x){
    super(x);
  }  
}

const c = new Child(20);
const copy = {...c, x: 10};

console.log(JSON.stringify(c));
c.squareX();
console.log(JSON.stringify(c));

console.log(JSON.stringify(copy));
copy.squareX();
console.log(JSON.stringify(copy));
```

Live demo: https://jsbin.com/wuqenabaya/1/edit?js,console

The idea is to create a copy of the instance `c` while updating some of it's properties. The output of this code is:

```
{x:  20, otherProperty: "preserve across copy"}
{x: 400, otherProperty: "preserve across copy"}
{x:  10, otherProperty: "preserve across copy"}
{x:  10, otherProperty: "preserve across copy"}
```

So as you can see the `copy.squareX()` does not update the instance `copy`. The issue is that the function `squareX()` is still bound to the old instance `c`.

What I want is to have the last call to `squareX()` to update the instance `copy`. How can this be achieved?

EDIT: I'm using Babel with following plugins, to allow the use of the new JS features (spread, function props).

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["es2015", { "modules": false }],
    "stage-0",
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "react-hot-loader/babel",
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    "transform-class-properties",
    "transform-flow-strip-types"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Note: "ES6" (ES2015) doesn't have spread properties. In fact, they aren't even in ES2017. They may be in ES2018; currently a [stage 3 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread).

Comment: is it an option to update the classes? i'm thinking of something like a static factory function that as argument accepts an class instance, reads the needed properties, generates a new instance, updates those properties, and returns the new instance. instead of cloning the old instance via object literal

Comment: Similarly, the [field declaration syntax](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) you're using is *also* not yet in any spec, and also at Stage 3.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I'm actually using Babel. I have update the answer to reflect this fact.

Comment: Well [just don't use arrow functions when you don't want your methods be bound](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/1048572) - the code would totally work with `function` expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with trying to use spread properties for this, not least that you'll end up with an object whose prototype is `Object.prototype`, not `Child.prototype`.

You're also using field syntax for methods, which makes those fields *own* properties of the object, not prototype properties, which there doesn't seem to be any reason for in this case; just use method syntax.

To do the copy, give yourself a "copy constructor" branch in your constructor:

```
constructor(x, ...more){
  if (x instanceof Child) {
    // The copy constructor branch
    super(x.x);
    Object.assign(this, x, ...more);
  } else {
    super(x);
  }
}
```

Or if you prefer, just do it where you create `copy`:

```
const copy = Object.assign(new Child(c.x), c, {x: 10});
```

In either case, if you choose to keep using fields rather than methods, you'll have to adjust things since otherwise you'll copy `squareX` and `printX` as well.

Live Example using methods and the copy constructor:

```js
class Parent {
  constructor(x){
    this.x = x;
    this.otherProperty = "preserve across copy";
  }

  printX() {
    console.log(this.x);
  }

  squareX() {
    this.x = this.x *this.x; 
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  constructor(x, ...more){
    if (x instanceof Child) {
      super(x.x);
      Object.assign(this, x, ...more);
    } else {
      super(x);
    }
  }  
}

const c = new Child(20);
const copy = new Child(c, {x: 10});

console.log(JSON.stringify(c));
c.squareX();
console.log(JSON.stringify(c));

console.log(JSON.stringify(copy));
copy.squareX();
console.log(JSON.stringify(copy));
```